# Intent Service blocking the UI

Tags: android, intentservice

I need to make so backround job without blocking user UI, so I made a test IntentService to check how it's work, but this intent services block the UI.
Here my Code on start app ic start service:

```
Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, AutoExchange.class);
        startService(msgIntent);
```

AutoExchange.java

```
public class AutoExchange extends IntentService{


public AutoExchange() {
    super("AutoExchange");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that this service block the main Ui, somethig I did wrong?

Comment: `IntentService` won't block UI thread since its executed on worker thread. Are you sure you are not doing some stuff, which is blocking UI thread, after you call `startService()`?

Comment: NO, i created empty app, on create i startservice and this is all, when in comment the startService everything is working

Comment: you can use asyncTask in a normal service instead.

Comment: @АлександрВолошиновский What is the output of `Thread.currentThread()` inside your service?

Comment: Sorry i'm using alarm manager for schedule service, and the alarm manager block main thread

Answer (score 0):

instead of thread.sleep() you can you handler

here is an example

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
},3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to make a new Runnable() around the try-catch-block.

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Your answer is wrong, Thread.sleep will block current thread and the running thread in IntentService is `BackgroundJobService`

Answer (score -1):

Register your service in android manifest.

Comment: It's wrong, If you don't register your service in andorid manifest, Android will not run your service even if you call `startService`